# 'Relation' in group representation and set theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I recently began studying abstract algebra and encountered the notion 'relation' at the section of group presentation. The definition given in the textbook was essentially same as the one from the article 'group presentation' in Wikipedia. Now it confuses me a bit because it seems possible to relate the concept with 'relation' from set theory in a sense; omitting the equality and identity symbol in presentation, the group elements tuple becomes an element of general n-ary relation.

I just want to make sure if the above concepts are identical or distinct. And if different, how.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: They are not related. You have to do a bit of work to give the intuitive notion of relation in group presentations a sufficiently precise meaning to implement it in set theory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are related. The group defined by a presentation is a quotient $F/N$, where $F$ is the free group on the generating set. We can define a relation (in the set-theoretic sense) $u \sim v$ on elements $u,v \in F$ by $u \sim v$ if and only if $uN=vN$. The relations $u=v$ in the presentation of $G$ (which I prefer to call defining relations) satisfy this relation $u \sim v$.

Conversely, for words $u,v$ with $u \sim v$,  we know that $u$ and $v$ represent the same element of $G$, and this is a consequence of the defining relations. (In fact $u=v$ is a relation that holds in $G$, but not necessarily a defining relation.)